# Correlation between two moving-average smoothed variables

Tags: time-series, correlation, smoothing

I have two time-series variables: mood and another external indicators. I want to compute the association between these variables. Let's say both have values for day 1 to N.

I compute two types of associations:

By simply correlating these two vectors of N elements each.
By correlating the variables after they are smoothed with moving-averages. So, I compute the moving-averages of these variables with a window of M. This is computed by taking the average of first M elements, then moving forward by leaving the first element and including the M+1-th element, and so on. Finally, I compute the correlation between these two vectors of N-M+1 elements each.
I don't see any correlation in the first case, however, in the seconds case I see a significantly moderate correlation. I am wondering if it is correct to use the correlations obtained by the second case. If not why?

Does the smoothening introduces temporal autocorrelation in both variables, which is the reason the I get significant correlation in the second case?

I tried to search for this but found only the question below that has no accepted answer yet.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239077/is-it-valid-to-get-a-correlation-between-moving-averages